# Правильно ли написано предложение с точки зрения русского языка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Заинтересовало написание следующего предложения: «Введите сумму целых», где слово «сумму» определяет не сумму сложения чисел, а количество валюты.
Всего ли хватает в данном предложении и что стоило бы внести в данное приложение, если чего-то нет?

Comment: Какую такую сумму целых?

Comment: Я думаю, что имеется в виду сумма целых, допустим, долларов в одной графе (8. только полн. Матем. Не содержащий дроби. Целое число. Целая величина.) В другой графе могут быть центы. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Answer (score 2):

Тут вот какое дело. [Сумма](http://endic.ru/academic/Summa-63128.html) — слово многозначное.
В указанном предложении имеется в виду такое значение:
определённое, то или иное **количество денег** (*Понемногу у меня набралась достаточная **сумма**, чтобы вернуться домой не с пустыми руками. На такую **сумму** можно раза три посидеть в кафе*).

Так что, думаю, все правильно в предложении: введите сумму платежа в рублях; ввести сумму перевода; введите сумму лимита в месяц или в сутки.

*Введите сумму в эстонских кронах или в евро* ([еврокалькулятор](https://www.kalkulaator.ee/ru/evrokalkulyator-ehstoniya)).

— Сколько вам нужно? **Назовите сумму.** Здесь вы все равно ничего не добьетесь, а если и добьетесь, то… [С. Д. Кржижановский. Воспоминания о будущем (1929)]